# How to pass data in angular 1.x

Tags: html, angularjs, json

How can I pass the data in my ng-repeat to a data-attribute?

Please see below what I'm aiming for.

Sorry for the poor format this is my first time posting to StackOverflow.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="p in controller.prod | filter:{state:'California'}">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h3 class="card-title">{{p.productName}}</h3>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">${{p.price}}</h6> 
        <img ng-src="{{p.productImage}}" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="card-block">
        <div class="card-text">Product information<a 
               href="#" 
               class="card-link productItem btn btn-primary" 
               <!--Below is what i'm trying to accomplish -->
               data-name="{{p.productName}}" 
               data-s="black" 
               data-price="{{p.price}}" 
               data-id="1">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is data-name data-price?

Comment: Data-name, data-price is what I'm doing to capture the value so I can store it in the session storage.

Answer (score 0):

you have to assign one array in $scope in your controller and after that bind it with ng-reapeat in your html template like this:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.records = [
        "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "Berglunds snabbköp",
        "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
        "Ernst Handel",
    ]
});
```

---

your template:

```
<h1 ng-repeat="x in records">{{x}}</h1>
```

Comment: Hi Hossein, the values are dynamic. I am try to get the value th user select to store it in session storage.